# How to start async threads on C++

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, asynchronous

- I want to have different **OpenCV** functions running with `std::async()`
- As an example, I'm trying to acquire and display images using my webcam.
- I did a class called `camHandler` to encapsulate this.
- This example is made asynchronous on purpose, I know I could just display the image after acquiring it :)

  1. I first use the `open()` function in a member `cap`:

```
auto camHandler::initCamera(int deviceID) -> camHandler::CamState {
    this->deviceID = deviceID;
    this->apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;
    cap.open(deviceID, apiID);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        this->currentState = error;
        return this->currentState;
    }
    return Ready;
}
```

2. I have a function for acquisition and another one for displaying:

```
auto camHandler::imageStreaming() -> void{
    this->currentState = streaming;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Acc " << std::endl;
        cap.read(this->frame);
        this->acquired++;
        if (this->frame.empty()) {
            this->currentState = error;
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

and

```
auto camHandler::displayImage() -> void { 
    while(true){
        std::cout << "Disp " << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("Live", this->frame);
        this->displayed++;
        if (cv::waitKey(5) >= 0){
            this->currentState = paused;
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

3. finally, I did a function that will call these 2 functions inside a `std::async()`:

```
auto camHandler::startStreaming() -> void { 
    auto stream = std::async(&camHandler::imageStreaming, this);
    auto disp = std::async(&camHandler::displayImage, this);
}
```

**The problem**

In my `main` I only call:

```
    camHandler ch;
    ch.initCamera();
    ch.startStreaming();
```

And I get:

```
Acc Disp 

Acc 
Acc 
Acc 
Acc 
Acc
```

Which means that display was only called once and acquisition kept running.

- How can I make sure both are running?
- Like this I don't even see the image window from OpenCV.
- My camera and display work properly when I do the normal capturing as shown in [OpenCV's Site](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html)

Comment: Can you provide a full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to call `cv::imshow` with an empty `cv::Mat`, it will throw an exception, and `async` will end.

Since it's running in async, `cv::imshow("Live", this->frame)` can be called before `cap.read(this->frame)`.
You should check `cv::Mat` is not empty before displaying.